# CastCompanionLibrary-android error code 138 when compiling

Tags: android, chromecast

I have setup CastCompanionLibrary-android as an android library project in Android Studio (0.4.4). I have added the following dependencies to build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
```

When building I always get this error.

```
     Execution failed for task ':castcompanion-lib:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M

    /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/build/bundles/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S 
    /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/build/res/all/debug -A 
    /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/build/bundles/debug/assets -m -J 
    /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/build/source/r/debug -F
    /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/build/libs/castcompanion-lib-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --non-constant-id --output-text-symbols /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/build/bundles/debug
    Error Code: 138
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT:

Switching the build tools to 18.1.1 is now showing me some different errors relating to the processing of the xml resources.

To switch the build tools I have modified my build.gradle to this:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
}
```

Note: minSdkVersion 9 (if this is lower then manifest merging fails).

At this point it uncovered 2 errors in the resource xml files...
To fix these errors I added the following lines to the res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="no_media_info">No media info</string>
<string name="media_route_menu_title">Media Router Title</string>
```

Now when I compile I get 33 errors, all related to resource processing ... it's progress of sorts but still feels like I'm doing something horribly wrong...

For completeness here is the full gradle output:

```
Executing tasks: [:castcompanion-lib:generateDebugSources, :chromecast-video:generateDebugSources]

Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:castcompanion-lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:preDebugTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71901Library UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV71901Library UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices4242Library UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:prepareDebugDependencies
:castcompanion-lib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:mergeDebugResources
:castcompanion-lib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:processDebugResources
:castcompanion-lib:generateDebugSources
:chromecast-video:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:chromecast-video:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:compileLint
:castcompanion-lib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:packageReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:castcompanion-lib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:castcompanion-lib:compileReleaseJava/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/BaseCastManager.java:685: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable session_reconnection_attempt
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                    dlg.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.session_reconnection_attempt));
                                                             ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/BaseCastManager.java:895: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_to_connect
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
            Utils.showErrorDialog(mContext, R.string.failed_to_connect);
                                                    ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/widgets/MiniController.java:127: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_perform_action
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                        listener.onFailed(R.string.failed_perform_action, -1);
                                                  ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/widgets/MiniController.java:129: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_no_connection_trans
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                        listener.onFailed(R.string.failed_no_connection_trans, -1);
                                                  ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/widgets/MiniController.java:131: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_no_connection
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                        listener.onFailed(R.string.failed_no_connection, -1);
                                                  ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/widgets/MiniController.java:147: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_perform_action
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                        listener.onFailed(R.string.failed_perform_action, -1);
                                                  ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:254: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable casting_to_device
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                    R.string.casting_to_device, mDeviceName));
                            ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:541: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_setting_volume
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                                onFailed(R.string.failed_setting_volume,
                                                 ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:824: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_status_request
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                                onFailed(R.string.failed_status_request,
                                                 ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:840: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_no_connection_trans
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
            onFailed(R.string.failed_no_connection_trans, NO_STATUS_CODE);
                             ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:843: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_no_connection
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
            onFailed(R.string.failed_no_connection, NO_STATUS_CODE);
                             ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:900: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_to_find_app
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                        Utils.showErrorDialog(mContext, R.string.failed_to_find_app);
                                                                ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:904: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_app_launch_timeout
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                        Utils.showErrorDialog(mContext, R.string.failed_app_launch_timeout);
                                                                ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:909: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_to_launch_app
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                        Utils.showErrorDialog(mContext, R.string.failed_to_launch_app);
                                                                ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:970: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_load
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                            onFailed(R.string.failed_load, result.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                                             ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:1016: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_to_play
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
            throw new CastException(mContext.getString(R.string.failed_to_play), e);
                                                               ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:1064: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_to_pause
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
            throw new CastException(mContext, R.string.failed_to_pause, e);
                                                      ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:1093: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_seek
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                            onFailed(R.string.failed_seek, result.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                                             ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:1122: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_seek
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                            onFailed(R.string.failed_seek, result.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                                             ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:1394: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_receiver_player_error
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                    onFailed(R.string.failed_receiver_player_error, NO_STATUS_CODE);
                                     ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java:1600: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable casting_to_device
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                                    R.string.casting_to_device, getDeviceName()))
                                            ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/dialog/video/VideoMediaRouteControllerDialog.java:141: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_no_connection_short
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
            hideControls(true, R.string.failed_no_connection_short);
                                       ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/player/VideoCastControllerActivity.java:146: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_no_connection_trans
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                            R.string.failed_no_connection_trans);
                                    ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/player/VideoCastControllerActivity.java:150: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_no_connection
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                            R.string.failed_no_connection);
                                    ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/player/VideoCastControllerActivity.java:154: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_perform_action
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                            R.string.failed_perform_action);
                                    ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/player/VideoCastControllerActivity.java:227: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable casting_to_device
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                mLine2.setText(getString(R.string.casting_to_device,
                                                 ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/player/VideoCastControllerActivity.java:237: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable casting_to_device
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                mLine2.setText(getString(R.string.casting_to_device,
                                                 ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/player/VideoCastControllerActivity.java:245: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable casting_to_device
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                mLine2.setText(getString(R.string.casting_to_device,
                                                 ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/player/VideoCastControllerActivity.java:251: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable loading
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                mLine2.setText(getString(R.string.loading));
                                                 ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/player/VideoCastControllerActivity.java:403: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable failed_setting_volume
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                    R.string.failed_setting_volume);
                            ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/notification/VideoCastNotificationService.java:304: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable casting_to_device
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
        String castingTo = getResources().getString(R.string.casting_to_device,
                                                            ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/utils/Utils.java:90: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable ok
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           ^
/Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/java/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/utils/Utils.java:88: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable error
location: class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.R.string
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle(R.string.error)
                                                          ^
33 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':castcompanion-lib:compileReleaseJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 26.581 secs
```

UPDATE:

Well in fact the above error was my own fault, it seems that when I set up the project in Android Studio and allowed Android Studio to merge the auto-generated res folder with the res folder from CastCompanionLibrary-android it did not do an overwrite so I ended up with some incorrect resources.

After replacing the bad res folder with the original one from CastCompanionLibrary-android git repo I now get a compilation error about duplicate resources ...

```
Execution failed for task ':castcompanion-lib:mergeReleaseResources'.
```

> /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/res/values/styles_democast.xml: Error: Duplicate resources: /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/res/values/styles_democast.xml:style/TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail.Light, /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/castcompanion-lib/src/main/res/values/styles_castvideo.xml:style/TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail.Light

Well, onwards we go....

UPDATE:

This is now compiling after basically closing Android Studio and replacing the res folder with the original res folder from CastCompanionLibrary-android.

UPDATE (project setup):

I created a new project and then created two modules. An android library module for CastCompanionLibrary-android and an android module for CastVideos-android. I copied in src and res folders from the original github projects ... the trick here is to close Android Studio first before doing that. Otherwise I think Android Studio tries do some merging of files. The build gradle for CastCompanion library is in the post above... you can safely use

```
compileSdkVersion 19, 
buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"
```

if you like... 18 seemed to give better errors regarding failure to process resources.

The CastVideos-android build.gradle is...

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':castcompanion-lib')
    compile files('libs/android-query.0.25.10.jar')
}`
```

Comment: I am running into the exact same problem right now, but I can't follow exactly what you did to get it working. Can you provide some more information about your setup and gradle files?

Comment: added more info to the post above, hope it helps a bit. Btw I then ran into a problem which I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784659/castvideos-android-duplicate-resources that might help too.