# CastVideos-android Duplicate resources

Tags: android, chromecast

I have spent quite a bit of time converting the [CastVideo-android example on github](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) into an AndroidStudio project.

I have run into this error,

```
Execution failed for task ':chromecast-video:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/chromecast-video/src/main/res/values/styles_democast.xml: Error: Duplicate resources: /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/chromecast-video/src/main/res/values/styles_democast.xml:style/TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail.Light, /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/ChromecastVideoTest/chromecast-video/src/main/res/values/styles_castvideo.xml:style/TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail.Light

According to a response to the issue I raised on the github repo https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/issues/2 this might be a an issue with my AndroidStudio setup ... it feels like the build needs to know which styles xml to process ...

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Or possibly suggest an easier way to build the googlecast android demos ?

Many thanks.

UPDATE:

Ok, it's not an answer but it might help someone temporarily until a real answer arrives...
In the end I just manually commented out the duplicate definitions from styles_democast.xml

Here is my updated res/styles/styles_democast.xml

```
     Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
     Copyright (C) 2012 readyState Software Ltd

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Democast" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_democast</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Democast</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Democast</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Democast</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Democast</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Democast</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_democast</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_democast</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Democast</item>

        <!-- item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/WhiteText</item -->


        <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Democast.Widget</item>

        <!-- Seekbar -->
        <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarAppTheme</item>
    </style>

    <!--
    style name="WhiteText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
      <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style
    -->

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Democast" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_democast</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_democast</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_democast</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Democast</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Democast" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_democast</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Democast</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Democast" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_democast</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Democast" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_democast</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Democast" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_democast</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Democast" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_democast</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_democast</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_democast</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Democast" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_democast</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Democast" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_democast</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Democast.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Democast</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Democast</item>
    </style>
<!--
    <style name="SeekBarAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">13dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">13dip</item>
        <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:thumbOffset">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
    </style>
-->

    <!-- goes below ... item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent.Democastoverlay</item -->
<!--
    <style name="Theme.DemocastOverlay" parent="@style/Theme.Democast">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>


    </style>
-->

    <!-- goes below .... item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Democastoverlay</item -->
<!--
    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Democastoverlay" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
            <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_democast</item>
            <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/WhiteText</item>

    </style>

    <style name="WhiteText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CastDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CastDialogWindowTitle</item>
    </style>
-->
    <!-- Show Case -->
    <!--
        <style name="ShowcaseButton">
            <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingBottom">15dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingLeft">35dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingRight">35dp</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
            <item name="android:background">@color/yellow</item>
        </style>

        <style name="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
            <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        </style>

        <style name="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail" parent="android:style/TextAppearance">
            <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        </style>

        <style name="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail.Light">
            <item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
            <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF0000</item>
            <item name="android:shadowRadius">0</item>
        </style>

        <style name="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title.Light">
            <item name="android:shadowRadius">0</item>
        </style>
    -->
</resources>
```

UPDATE 2:

A comment was made about another post at [CastCompanionLibrary-android error code 138 when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779023/)

That post relates to issues with getting github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android to compile. The CastCompanionLibrary (CCL) is required as a dependency by CastVideos-android so some of the info there might help anyone who is generally running into difficultly building the android chromecast examples in Android Studio.

Comment: See if this post and what the user did there might be relevant to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779023/castcompanionlibrary-android-error-code-138-when-compiling

Comment: hehe, that was my post from earlier today, getting the CastCompanionLibrary-android to build in Android Studio was quite a struggle. Anyway feels like I'm nearly there, I probably need to do some more research into how android styles are processed by Android Studio / gradle.

Comment: If that was your post, why did you post this one???

Comment: The other post was all about issues with getting the CCL to build in Android Studio. This post is related to CastVideos-android. They are different issues. If you read the other post carefully you will realise that the final issue was a red herring, somehow the resources from CastVideos-android had ended up in the CCL module, amongst other things.... anyway I have updated my post with a workaround until a real solution can be found. I am now able to build and run the CastVideos-android example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because you have `TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail.Light` in both `styles_democast.xml` and `styles_castvideo.xml`